# Power BI Quiz - need clarification on a question

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

I have this question before me.

You plan to use Power BI Desktop to create a report. The report will consume data from an on-premises tabular named SalesDB in Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS). The report will be published to the Power BI service. You need to ensure that the report published to the Power BI service will access the current data in SalesDB. What should you do?

A. Deploy an on-premises data gateway and configure the connection to SalesDB to use the Import Data Connectivity mode.

B. Deploy an **on-premises data gateway** and configure the connection to SalesDB to use the **Connect live option.**

C. Deploy an on-premises data gateway (personal mode) and configure to SalesDB to use the DirectQuery Data Connectivity mode.

D. Deploy an **on-premises data gateway** and configure the connection to SalesDB to use the **DirectQuery** Data Connectivity mode.

Is the correct answer B or D ?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the answer should be B. You can access SSAS only using Live Connect and Import method.